# String Replace PNG For Jpg

Tags: sql, string, replace, opencart

I have just finished importing my images into opencart. I now noticed that OpenCart doesn't handle PNG graphics properly as it uses a static rate for compression which works fairly well for JPG but ends up losslessly compressing PNG which isn't so great.

I have now converted the png images to Jpeg, but im wondering if the its possible to replace the image name using MySql.

Is there any way to replace the image link for URL.

Comment: You might want to explain a bit more what you have done, what needs to be done and where you have problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponses guys. Dave, Will give that code a run now!!

Comment: Thanks Dave Worked like a charm!